# How to take screenshot of a newly loaded webpage

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, screenshot, webdriverwait

I am using selenium to login to a webpage and take a screenshot post login. Here is my code :

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("some website")
user_name = driver.find_element_by_name("USERNAME")
password = driver.find_element_by_name("PIN")

user_name.clear()
user_name.send_keys("username")

password.clear()
password.send_keys("password)

###Sends enter
password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# Wait for some time for the next page to load
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')
driver.quit()
```

When I do this, I get the screenshot of the login page instead of the next page.

The expected output ideally should be a screenshot of the page, post login.
I have manually verified by monitoring that selenium opens the webpage, logins,
within 10 seconds.

So I did something else, i inserted sleep (10) instead of driver.wait, like this :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
```

replaced with

```
os.sleep(10)
```

On doing this, I get the screenshot of the next page.

I then also tried to insert a custom wait condition, and searched for an element in the next page :

```
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "crnum"))
    )
```

However, selenium is giving me the following error :

```
TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-16f1ee0dd7f3> in <module>()
     15 try:
     16     element = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
---> 17         EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "crnum"))
     18     )
     19 finally:

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py in until(self, method, message)
     78             if time.time() > end_time:
     79                 break
---> 80         raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
     81 
     82     def until_not(self, method, message=''):

TimeoutException: Message:
```

I have checked the second page , and the id exists there.
I believe what is happening is selenium is still trying to search the element on the loading page.

I manually verified by monitoring the other page and it opens in under two second.

**EDIT :**

Html code present in the second page, i am searching by id :

```
<input type="text" id="crnum" name="number" title="Request Number" onfocus="this.className='focusField';" onblur="this.className='';" class="">
```

Comment: I see no `element = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "crnum")))` line in your code

Comment: @Andersson Have edited the  the question.

Comment: @avinash Update the question with the HTML of the element you have identified as `(By.ID, "crnum")`

Comment: @avinash `wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)` is not a wait for page to load. This line does nothing actually

Comment: @Andersson How do I then wait for the next page to load.

Comment: @DebanjanB I have updated the html code present in the second page.Also when i put sleep(10) in my code, i get the screen shot of the second page.

Answer (score 1):

To get the screenshot of the *Next Page* (newly loaded page) you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the identified element on the next page to be clickable and you can use the following code block :

```
password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
# Wait for the element with text as Request Number to be clickable
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='crnum' and @name='number' and @title='Request Number']")))
driver.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')
driver.quit()
```

---

### Reference

You can find a detailed discussion in [How to take screenshot with Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/how-to-take-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver/55120087#55120087)

Comment: I added the clickable line but I am still getting the error. For some reason, selenium is still searching the old page instead of the newly loaded page.

Comment: Delete the existing attachment first. Execute your program. Refresh your _Project Space_ and have a fresh look at the snapshot.

Comment: Hi, Debanjan did the above, the error still persists.I am able to take the screenshot by putting time.sleep(4) before taking the screenshot.Not sure what is happening.

Comment: Can you share the _url_ incase it's a public _url_?

Comment: It's internal company url, i wish i could share it as i really want to debug this. Can you explain why checking elements_to_be_clickable is better/more accurate than presense_of_elements_locatable?

Comment: @avinash Check this discussion [**`WebDriverWait not working as expected`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808)